# Entropy after removing partition separating two gases system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

> An ideal gas is seperated by a piston in such a way that the entropy of one prat is$ S_1$ and that of the other part is $S_2$. Given that $S_1>S_2$, if the piston is removed then the total entropy of the system will be..?
>
> Ans: $S_1 +S_2$
>
> JEE Mains March 18th evening attempt 2021

I know that for an ideal gas, the entropy is given as:

$$ S = nC_v \ln T -nR \ln V+C$$

Let the variables of one compartment be $(V,T)$ and the other be $(V',T')$ the combined variables be $(\tilde{V},\tilde{T})$. Now according to the question:

$$ nC_v \ln \tilde{T} - nR \ln \tilde{V} + C = nC_v \ln TT' - nR \ln VV' +2C$$

I simply can't see how the above equation is true! Is there some concept which can be used to simplify understanding the above?

P.S: We aren't taught statistical mechanics for this test

Note: C is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that the final entropy will be $S_1+S_2$ is if the initial temperatures and the initial pressures in the two chambers are equal.

This is for @Buraian:

To get the final temperature and pressure, we use the conditions that the change in internal energy of the combined system is zero, and the final volume is equal to the initial combined volume.  This leads to:

$$n_1C_v(T_F-T_1)+n_2C_v(T_F-T_2)=0$$and$$\frac{n_1RT_1}{P_1}+\frac{n_2RT_2}{P_2}=\frac{(n_1+n_2)RT_F}{P_F}$$The solutions to these equations for $T_F$ and $P_F$ are:
$$T_F=\frac{n_1T_1+n_2T_2}{(n_1+n_2)}$$$$\frac{1}{P_F}=\left(\frac{n_1T_1}{n_1T_1+n_2T_2}\right)\frac{1}{P_1}+\left(\frac{n_2T_2}{n_1T_1+n_2T_2}\right)\frac{1}{P_2}$$The entropy change for the system is given by:
$$\Delta S=n_1C_p\ln{\left(\frac{T_F}{T_1}\right)}+n_2C_p\ln{\left(\frac{T_F}{T_2}\right)}+n_1R\ln{\left(\frac{P_1}{P_F}\right)}+n_2R\ln{\left(\frac{P_2}{P_F}\right)}$$The next step is to show that, unless the initial temperatures and pressures are equal, this entropy change is positive definite.

I'm going to stop here for now. If anyone is interested in my continuing this development to prove the above, please indicate so in a comment and I will continue.

Comment: What about the constant on the right? Further, I don't think pressure and T is equal because they told entropy in each container is different.

Comment: The entropies can be different if there are different amounts of gas in the two chambers even if the temperatures and pressure are equal.  The change in total entropy can not be zero if the temperatures and/or pressures in the two containers are not equal; entropy will be generated when the system re-equilibrates.

Comment: Right, but that is explaining from the answer. Do you agree that the question is perhaps incomplete in the amount of given information?

Comment: @ Buraian I don't think that it is incomplete, assuming a rigid insulated container.  Did you want me to derive the equation for the entropy change in terms of $n_1,T_1,P_1$ and $n_2,T_2,P_2$, and show that it is positive unless the initial temperatures and pressures are both equal?

Comment: You have mentioned it is $S_1 +S_2$ if and only if the initial temperature and intial pressure are not equal, this concept is not mentioned in the question, yet $S_1  + S_2$ is answered. Hence, I think the information is incomplete to solve the question

Comment: @Buraian You allow too much respect for the people who devised this question.

Comment: You are most probably right, for the thing about entropy.  I tried writing my own proof. Let the compartment with greater temperature be $T_2$ and the other one be $T_1$, let $d Q$ be transfered from compartment with $T_2$ into one with $T_1$:

$$ \frac{-dQ}{T_2} + \frac{dQ}{T_1} = dS$$

Is true for all points in the process. But, $\frac{dQ}{T_1}> \frac{dQ}{T_2}$, hence $dS>0$.

I am a bit confused as to where pressure comes in here

Comment: @Buraian That is definitely not the way to proceed.  The first step should be to derive equations for the final temperature and final pressure of the gas, based on the initial temperatures, pressures, and numbers of moles.

Comment: @Buraian See the text I added on your behalf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129090/discussion-between-buraian-and-chet-miller).